# C++ Получать список сайтов, по которым переходит пользователь

Tags: c++, url, браузер

Мне нужно понять, в какую сторону двигаться для того, чтобы осуществить перехват всех ссылок, по которым переходит пользователь. Суть в чем: перейдя в любой браузер, пользователь каким-либо образом переходит на сайт. и я хочу, чтобы URL(каждый, учитывая переходы) перехватывался и записывался в какой-нибудь файлик(это я уже сам, для понимания указал). Итак, как это реализовать в C++? Любой книжный материал или практический опыт будут очень полезны!

Comment: пишете свой браузер и все сохраняете

Comment: почитать серию журналов хакер. Практический опыт слежки за пользователями - возможно тянет на статью))))) вы не из службы какой-либо интересной?

Comment: @KoVadim можно плагин к браузеру. У плагина есть доступ к такой информации.

Comment: возможно, но человеку на с++ нужно

Comment: Как вариант: посмотрите в сторону отслеживания сокетов и анализа их данных